# How to set LinearLayout background image to fill the screen

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` with a background image set and I want the image to keep its aspect ratio because now it gets modified by the screen size. In xcode you can set the imageView property `Aspect fill` but in eclipse I can't find a solution for this problem.. This is my `LinearLayout` xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" >
```

Comment: I think fitCenter solve your issue . Did you try ?

Comment: I think you need to use a 9patch image for background. 9patch image will automatically manage with different resolutions.

Comment: @salih I tried but it doesn't work..

Comment: @Signo, are you using lolipop ?

Comment: @HirenPatel no my minsdk is api 9

Comment: @Signo, m not talking about min sdk, I mean which device you are using ?

Comment: @HirenPatel yes Lollipop

Comment: The `scaleType` attribute is only used by **src**, not by **background**.

Comment: @DerGol...lum damn ok ty! So is chinmay ghag the only correct solution?

Comment: No... there are also 9 patches, which offer a **selective stretching**.

Comment: @DerGol...lum ok! but since my image is complex I can't use 9 patches (at least this is what I understood reading some documentation), ty again for explaining!

Comment: OK, then the best answer so far is the one from @ChinmayGag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case you have a few drawable folders in which you need to keep images that corresponds to the respective device dimensions.
i.e.
HDPI - have a different resolution image
MDPI,XHDPI,XXHDPI are various types of dpi's used

for further info here is the link where u can get the exact dimensions:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:scaleType="fitXY"` 
solve your issue . Kindly Try once.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Layout should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapp" >
```

I have same issue before five days, I have resolved it by adding **fill_parent** on **width** and **height**, I was surprised when I have resolved my issue.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: `fill_parent` is **deprecated** since API Level 8. Please, use `match_parent`, instead.

Comment: @DerGol...lum, yes bro but I have resolved same issue.

Comment: I don't think it was because of **this**. The attributes do **the same thing**, no difference. But one is deprecated, the other one is accepted. You surely did some other modifications that solved your issue.

Comment: @DerGol...lum, specially for Lolipop.